# Prevent ignoring non 200 response status - Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, http-status-code-502

I'm crawling a website which I want to retry the request when getting response status 50x, but I'm getting

> ignoring non-200 response

How can I get rid of that and retry the request few times (3 times for example in default) or retry until get 200 response status.

```
DEBUG:scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry:Retrying <GET http://sample.com/> (failed 1 times): 502 Bad Gateway
DEBUG:scrapy.core.engine:Crawled (502) <GET http://sample.com/> (referer: None)
CRITICAL:security_daily_history:<twisted.python.failure.Failure scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpError: Ignoring non-200 response>
```

**Update:**

My custom retry middleware is:

```py
class CustomRetryMiddleware(RetryMiddleware):

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        super().process_response(request, response, spider)
        return response
```

which should work just like built in `RetryMiddleware` but it doesn't, I set `RETRY_TIMES = 4` in my setting but spider is ignoring `502` status after failed 1 time. to reproduce the problem [this link](http://getstatuscode.com/502) always returns 502 status code.
I enabled my custom middleware in setting by:

```py
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
   'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
   'projectname.middlewares.CustomRetryMiddleware': 543,
}
```

Comment: you should `return super()...` instead of `return response`

Answer (score 2):

Your request should already be retried two times by the RetryMiddleware, according to [the docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#retry-times). In my opinion, this can also be seen from your logs, because you have `Crawled (xxx) <GET http://sample.com/>` in there two times (one time with 502, one time with 200)`

You can adjust the number of retries with an attribute in your request:

> Maximum number of retries can also be specified per-request using max_retry_times attribute of Request.meta. When initialized, the max_retry_times meta key takes higher precedence over the RETRY_TIMES setting.

Didn't try it now, but this should probably look like so when you create and yield the original request:

```py
request_with_cookies = Request(
    url='http://www.example.com', meta={'max_retry_times': 10})
```

The request for `http://www.example.com` would then be retried up to a maximum of 10 times.

If the request fails too often, your request will be ignored by the `scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware` (cf your log message).

According to the scrapy docs it's possible to [define a list of error codes that your spider can handle](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware) with the attribute `handle_httpstatus_list` in your spider. This would be useful if you want to handle the request in your spider even if it failed k times.

```py
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    handle_httpstatus_list = [404]
```

In this specific case, since you are experiencing a 502 error, you'd want to use `handle_httpstatus_list = [502]` (only if you really want to handle it, but I guess what you want is to adjust the retry count in the RetryMiddleware?).

I do not see a possibility in the docs to run a request until a success code is returned. This makes sense, because it would introduce infinite loops in the scraping process. If you want to retry until a success code is returned, just set the number of retries to a very high number, e.g. `max_retry_times = 100`. If there is no success after 100 times, it will most likely not change anytime soon.

Comment: you are perfectly right and showed helpful points, but the problem is when I'm using built in middleware it works fine and after retrying 4 times it gives up retrying but when I'm using custom middleware which I wrote and added as update in question it does retry only 1 time and then Ignore for unknown reason.